# Sony Vaio Duo 11 - Secure Dual Boot - Ubuntu and Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

Edited Question:

How to have a secure dual boot running with Linux and Windows 10 on Sony Vaio Duo 11?

Answer,

see below.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode as required for dual booting with another OS installed the same way? The Boot-Repair tool can generate a useful report. Please run it again, generate the report, edit and paste the link into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should not have sped read this [Ubuntu article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Laptop/Sony/Vaio/Duo11/Trusty) the first few times I came upon it. It has one sentence that could have saved me a month of headache; [the laptop is] hard-coded to boot from the file /dev/sda3/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi

Knowing this, the solution became pretty easy. 
1. Move or rename /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi to /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/xxxx.efi (or whatever you would like to name that file).
2. Move or copy all the contents of the linux boot folder to /EFI/Microsoft/Boot
3. Rename or copy shimx64.efi or shim.efi to bootmgfw.efi
4. Edit grub's custom_40 file to point to windows' xxxxxx.efi. This is the code to use:

menuentry "Windows 10" {
        insmod part_gpt

```
    insmod chain

    set root='(hd0,gpt1)'

    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/xxxxx.efi
```

}

5. Update grub and copy the new grub.cfg to /EFI/Microsoft/Boot
6. Reboot and enjoy.

I tested this technique with Fedora 25 and Kubuntu 16.10.

You want to know the funny part about this whole debacle? I solved the issue after deleting Windows... go figure. I currently boot with secure boot on for an OS that doesn't need it. Hahahaha....

For Alex;

I accidentally deleted Windows in this particular laptop, so my 40_custom file is blank. I found the code to use in [rod's page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/grub2.html)... scroll down to the part where it says configuring grub 2 and you will see this code;

```
  menuentry "Windows 7" {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod chain
        set root='(hd0,gpt1)'
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/xxxxx.efi
}
```

This is what you paste at the bottom of the 40_custom file. Make sure that the chainloader DOES NOT point to the bootmgfw.efi and instead points to the windows efi file you renamed. If it points to the bootmgfw.efi, selecting the option windows will just load grub again. Also make sure that '(hd0,gpt1)' points to the actual partition where your efi partition is. I don't remember how the partitions are laid out since I accidentally wiped out this HD (ooopss). Also please note my updated steps above. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem with the same laptop. I can boot into Ubuntu after doing steps 1 to 3 but on my Ubuntu 16.04 box I don't have a valid /etc/grub.d/40_custom file for booting into Windows 10. Could you please update your answer and supply your 40_custom file? Thanks!